# Using an XML file as my Winforms .NET 2.0 datasource

Tags: .net, xml, winforms, datasource

Is it possible to point to an xml file as a datasource in the same way you would with an .mdf file? Please let me know if I can clarify this question.

For example, let's say I have a datagrid and I want to connect a datasource to it and I want that datasource to be based on a local filesystem xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [DataSet.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325639(VS.71).aspx) method.

> The ReadXml method provides a way to
>   read either data only, or both data
>   and schema into a DataSet from an XML
>   document.